# com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreNeedIndexException: no matching index found

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I am getting the following exception when I am deploying my APP of Google App Engine server with Objectify, although I have already configured all the indexes of my application. Still didn't understand why I am getting this exception, due to this error, I am not able to do anything on this web application.

**Exception in Production Server**

```
/search
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreNeedIndexException: no matching index found.
The suggested index for this query is:
<datastore-index kind="M_TAXI" ancestor="false" source="manual">
    <property name="cityName" direction="asc"/>
    <property name="updatedOn" direction="asc"/>
</datastore-index>
```

**datastore.indexes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datastore-indexes autoGenerate="true">
<datastore-index kind="M_COUNTRY" ancestor="false" source="auto">
 <property name="countryCode" direction="asc" />
 <property name="countryName" direction="asc" />
 <property name="active" direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="M_CITY" ancestor="false" source="auto">
 <property name="countryCode" direction="asc" />
 <property name="cityName" direction="asc" />
 <property name="cityCode" direction="asc" />
 <property name="active" direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="M_TAXI" ancestor="false" source="auto">
 <property name="cityName" direction="asc" />
 <property name="supplierUserName" direction="asc" />
 <property name="updatedOn" direction="asc" />
 <property name="active" direction="asc" />
 <property name="countryName" direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
</datastore-indexes>
```

**Datastore index image snapshot from production server**

[image: Datastore index image snapshot]

Comment: It seems quite clear that you don't have the precise index the error is calling for. What about that is confusing you?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am confused because I have clearly defined all indexes then why appengine is giving this error.

Comment: But you haven't! The error says it needs an index for M_TAXI with cityName/updatedOn. You don't have that, you only have a single index for that kind with five properties. It doesn't want a five-property index, it wants a two-property one.

Comment: @DanielRoseman can you please give an answer with some sample code, as I am still confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The existing M_TAXI is not usable by the query that threw the exception.  Please try inserting

```
<datastore-index kind="M_TAXI" ancestor="false" source="manual">
    <property name="cityName" direction="asc"/>
    <property name="updatedOn" direction="asc"/>
</datastore-index>
```

into datastore.indexes.xml before the </datastore-indexes> end tag and after the other M_TAXI element, and report back what the result was.

Comment: do I need to add multiple <datastore-index/> if I need to have multiple types of filters.

Comment: The two indexes on the M_TAXI kind are different because of the fields they contain.  So yes, add multiple distinct entries.

Comment: Thanks for your help, now its working but still I didn't got for last 2 years I have working with appengine, I never created any **datastore-indexes.xml** manually, it was taken care by Objectify **@Index** annotation automatically. Is there any changes in appengine or objectify configurations ?

Comment: The [Datastore Indexes](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/indexes) docs say "The development server automatically adds suggestions to this file as it encounters queries that cannot be executed with the existing indexes".  It usually happens unnoticed in the background, but you must execute every type of query on the development server.  This query seems to have escaped into production untested.

Answer (score 3):

You  must add these index in your `datastore.indexes.xml`

```
<datastore-index kind="M_TAXI" ancestor="false" source="manual">
    <property name="cityName" direction="asc"/>
    <property name="updatedOn" direction="asc"/>
</datastore-index>
```

As Appengine datastore is schemaless, you must need to add seperate indexes for different query.

Please refer this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115270/google-app-engine-composite-index-re-use).